# Different ouput for pd.str.extract() and re.search()

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

As seen in my previous question

[Rename columns regex, keep name if no match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838810/rename-columns-regex-keep-name-if-no-match)

Why is there a different output of the regex?

```
data = {'First_Column': [1,2,3], 'Second_Column': [1,2,3], 
        '\First\Mid\LAST.Ending': [1,2,3], 'First1\Mid1\LAST1.Ending': [1,2,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

     First_Column   Second_Column   \First\Mid\LAST.Ending  First1\Mid1\LAST1.Ending
```

pd.str.extract()

```
df.columns.str.extract(r'([^\\]+)\.Ending')   

    0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   LAST
3   LAST1
```

re.search()

```
col = df.columns.tolist()
for i in col[2:]:
    print(re.search(r'([^\\]+)\.Ending', i).group())

LAST.Ending
LAST1.Ending
```

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) docs

> Extract capture groups in the regex pat as columns in a DataFrame.

It returns the capture group. Whereas, [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with `group()` or `group(0)` returns the whole match, but if you change to `group(1)` it will return the capture `group 1`.

This will return full match:

```
 for i in col[2:]:
    print(re.search(r'([^\\]+)\.Ending', i).group())

LAST.Ending
LAST1.Ending
```

This will return only the capture group:

```
 for i in col[2:]:
    print(re.search(r'([^\\]+)\.Ending', i).group(1))

LAST
LAST1
```

Further read [`Link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728729/python-group0-meaning/36729594)